# Deny keycloak user rights to push to private doocker registry

Tags: docker, registry, keycloak

I have a private docker registry and a keycloak instance, both of which are running in a docker container. Keycloak already has a user that can pull from and push to the registry, but I want to create an additional user that is allowed to pull images, but cannot push anything to the registry. How can I achieve this?